# Use script in an alias

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-mate, alias

Can I use this script in an alias?

```
MOV="$*"
FILENAME=$(basename "${MOV// /_}" | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/').mp3
ffmpeg -i "${MOV}" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 "${FILENAME}"
```

Comment: Why do you want it in an alias? I would put it in a directory in PATH and use it as it is. If only you should use it, put it into your `~/bin` directory (create that directory if necessary), if others should use it too, put it in '/usr/local/bin`

Comment: man bash states: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."